# How to phrase "two companies being the most successful one in their respective countries" as a noun-phrase?

Tags: grammar, sentence

How to express this in one sentence: there are two companies, one is the most successful in America, and the other the most successful in Canada.

Can we say it like this?

> they are **the most successful two companies in Canada and America**.

or is it like this?

> they are **the two most successful companies in Canada and America**.

If both of the above sentences are wrong, how to express it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your sentences indicate that the two companies are Number 1 and Number 2 in the **whole** of North America, and that there no companies from either country ahead of them. Neither sentence is the equivalent of saying that Company A is top of the US and Company B is top in Canada, and you could stand accused of making an unfounded claim.

If you need to indicate that their status is country-specific, you do need to say that.

What you could say (and probably justify) is that the two companies are among the most successful in the United States and Canada; but again, that doesn't indicate that either is top in their respective country.

How about something like the following (which I've just noticed you have suggested in the question title)?

> We refer to Company A in the United States and Company B in Canada, the most successful in their respective countries.

Comment: So the 2 sentences I made are not grammartically wrong, just don't indicate what I meant, right?

Comment: They are not grammatically wrong (although the first is awkward; the second is better). They mean the same thing, and do not mean what you want them to mean.

Answer (score 2):

I would express it like this:

> X and Y are the most successful companies in Canada and the US,
>   respectively.

Just make sure that X is the Canadian company and Y is the US one.

Also, as a side note, "successful" is an awfully vague adjective -- you might want to clarify what you mean by that (most profitable, largest market share, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> "Company A is the most successful company in the United States, but in Canada it's Company B."

The most precious resource to conserve in writing is your reader's brain.

Comment: Perhaps true, but grammar's still (arguably) important. There needs to be either a semicolon in place of that comma or some sort of conjunction following it.

Comment: Less work for the reader always trumps.  But I concede, @onomatomaniak, it's better with a conjunction.